# Finding records that contain keywords

Tags: php, mysql, performance, mysqli

I have two tables.

table 1 - with 500+ keywords

```
id
keyword
```

table 2

```
id
title
desc
content
...
```

I'm looking for best way to select all records from table 2, where title field contain one or more keywords from table 1. I think LIKE, REGEX isn't good choice due to performance. To first and the second table, I constantly add new records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `concat` and `like` like so:

```
SELECT * FROM table_2 AS t2
LEFT JOIN table_1 AS t1 ON t2.title LIKE CONCAT('%', t1.keyword, '%');
```

Check this [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17768/3)

Comment: you need to adjust the select * to not bring back duplicate column names, and to deal with the fact that you are doing a left join and bringing back nulls on non matches (the edge condition you did not show in the test data)

Comment: and this would be the fiddle to look at to fix [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18681/1)

Comment: i know, i can handle it :)